# how to find out a java Component being displayed on screen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to find out if a JPanel is on the screen or not. It doesn't mean that `isVisible()` method could be used for this situation. I mean I want to find out whether a component that has been initiated before, presently is one of components on my main panel or not.

Edit and more explanation: I have several panels initiated before in my program and use them on my form as needed. I want to know for example `jpanel1` in now on any of panels that now are present on my form.

Example:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame() {

    private JPanel1, jPanel2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new JPanel();
        gui.setContentpane(jPanel1);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

now `jPanel1` is visible on screen bu `jPanel2` is not visible.
How can I find out this?

Comment: yes is possible, can you please edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) , maybe there are another choices

Comment: DO you mean isShowing()?: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isShowing()

Comment: @mKorbel : is clear and I explained as I mean.

Comment: @Guillaume PoletIt: I have investigated it before but I didn't find my goal

Comment: @sajad, What is the goal? Your explanation of the problem did not help!

Comment: Also it's useful to know [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: @  Moonbeam: please see my edits

Comment: I added an example. Please see it.

Comment: @sajad see my answer, it can solve your problem surely. you do not have to change so much code since mypanel extends jpanel.

Comment: What happens if the component is `setVisible(true)` but the bounds of the component are outside the JPanel so the user can't actually see it. What will `isVisible`, `isDisplayable` and `isShowing` output?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After investigation I find out this method represents that the component is displayed on screen or not:

> isDisplayable()

in my Example:

> `jPanel1.isDisplayable()` // returns true
>
> `jPanel2.isDisplayable()` // returns false

as Simple as this!

Comment: @mKorbel so i reinvented the wheel? :)

Comment: @deporter I think so no :-), basically your answer goes correct direction, because you must to know in every moments what, where and how your code works

Comment: @mKorbel it's not a wheel, it's more like an triangle ;-)

Comment: In my application this method does _NOT_ return false if a component is not on screen.  The correct method to call is [`Component.isShowing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isShowing--).  I say this, but I still cannot be sure `isShowing()` is the correct method, but I know `isDisplayable()` is incorrect.  Once someone verifies this and updates the answer I'll take away my down vote.

Comment: What happens if the component is `setVisible(true)` but the bounds of the component are outside the JPanel so the user can't actually see it. What will `isVisible`, `isDisplayable` and `isShowing` output?

Answer (score 5):

`jPanel1.isVisible()==true`
`jPanel1.isVisible()==false`

for panel
`jPanel1.isShowing()` also works

Comment: Yes, `isShowing()` is working fine for components in tabs

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for children of a main panel, you could call `getComponents()` on the main panel to return an array of its Components, then iterate through them to check if any of them are the Panel you are looking for. You may need to call this recursively if the panel is not a direct child of the main panel.

Comment: no Mr. I have several panels initiated before in my program and use them on my form as needed. I want to know for example jpanel1 in now on any of panels that now are present on my form.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own panel class that extends `JPanel`. Add a new method to this class named `isOnTheScreen()` which return a *boolean* indicating whether the panel is added to the window or not.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    boolean isAdded = false;

    public boolean isOnTheScreen()
    {
       return isAdded;
    }

    public void setOnTheScreen(boolean isAdded)
    {
       this.isAdded = isAdded;
    }
}
```

After creating your own panel objects, use the methods above to learn whether a panel is added to main panel/frame or not. Suppose you have added a panel to a frame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame()
MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
panel.setOnTheScreen(true);
```

As soon as you add it to the main screen, in this case a frame, call `setOnTheScreen(true)`
And similarly call `setOnTheScreen(false)` when you remove the panel.

After this design you can determine whether a panel is added to the main window or not by just invoking `isOnTheScreen()` anywhere else in your code. I hope this design helps you.

Comment: thank you but this is not a very clean way. This is hard to apply this in all of my panels. I added an example of my pourpse. Please see it

Comment: @sajad this is a very clean way. if you believe in the power of inheritance, extending jpanel shouldn't be difficult. anyway, it's just a suggestion, then you have to find another solution.

Comment: -1 a) duplicating existing functionality, only worse (needs calling from client code to be effective) b) don't subclass if you don't have to (_shouldn't be difficult_ is not a good enough reason). @sajad well spotted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Call [Component::isShowing.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#isShowing()) Even that comes with a couple of caveats.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that if the component is out of bounds of the JFrame, you won't see it, but each of these methods returns `true`. To find out whether the component is really visible, use `(jframe.getBounds().contains(jPanel.getBounds())&&jPanel.isShowing())`